# Lambda Expression X linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expressões-lambda

Falando em termos de performance no todo(velocidade, integridade e etc...), usar expressões lambdas para consultar banco de dados, é melhor nos termos acima ou não ou depende?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para o caso de objetos que implementam `IQueryable`, há o tempo da construção da sentença que consome algum processamento, portanto, partindo de termos absolutos, a sentença em SQL estático será **ou mais rápida ou equivalente** ao SQL gerado.

Entretanto, falando em integridade e consistência, o SQL estático, apenas, não garante. **Todo o mapeamento de dados entre as estruturas da linguagem de programação precisa ser feito manualmente pelo programador**, o que pode produzir erros comuns como a falta de colunas e/ou informações que podem causar erros na execução de um fluxo trivial do sistema.

No caso do *Entity Framework*, ao persistir dados, o Framework realiza algumas verificações automaticamente, o que melhora a consistência e a integridade referencial (**não garante 100%**, mas melhora). Se o código é gerado a partir de um banco de dados que já existe (*Database First*), os objetos do Modelo terão copiar fidedignamente o banco. Se o banco é gerado a partir do código (*Code First*), toda e qualquer validação colocada como configuração será replicada para a base.

Comparando uma e outra, `Expression Methods` (vulgo `lambda`) e `LINQ`, não há diferença em performance, visto que ambas montam o objeto `IQueryable` de maneira muito similar. A diferença mesmo está na expressividade de cada uma. `Expression Methods` são mais sucintos, enquanto que `LINQ` é mais didática e clara por se aproximar de uma linguagem natural, no caso, o inglês.

Comment: Ok, mas nesse caso, conforme eu perguntei, a comparação entre linq e lambda dentro do que vc falou, tem como dizer se essa é melhor do que aquela ou ambas são equivalentes no contexto performance.

Comment: @pnet Atualizei pra você.

Answer (score 0):

Diferença há sim. Lambda Expression é mais performático que LINQ. Segue link que comprova o que digo. [http://imasters.com.br/artigo/15036/dotnet/comparativo-de-performance-linq-lambda-e-dynamic-linq](http://imasters.com.br/artigo/15036/dotnet/comparativo-de-performance-linq-lambda-e-dynamic-linq/)

Comment: Fábio, bem vindo ao Stackoverflow! Agradecemos você querer ajudar! No entanto, a sua resposta se resume a um link que neste momento é válido mas nada nos garante que continue a sê-lo no futuro. O stackoverflow deve ser encarado como um repositório de conhecimento e não apenas um site de pergunta resposta. Ao responder devemos pensar, não só em quem perguntou, mas em todos aqueles que no futuro poderão usufruir da nossa resposta.

Comment: Só para constar, o exemplo deste site é falho, ele nunca enumera os valores o que faz que que tanto a expressão lambda quando a query linq nunca sejam realmente executadas.